# how to use indexOf method for double array in java

Tags: java, arrays, double

I am trying to find the index of a double in a double array, it works for strings and integer arrays but not double.

```
double[] a = {1.1,2.2,3.3};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a).indexOf(1.1));
```

It keeps returning -1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't work with `int` array either. `Arrays.asList(a)` returns a `List<double[]>` whose single element is the input array, so it doesn't contain the element `1.1`.

Try

```
Double[] a = {1.1,2.2,3.3};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a).indexOf(1.1));
```

instead.

Comment: what is input array?

Comment: @NigelNg the array you pass to `Arrays.asList()` (`a` in your example).